# Convert sql result (object) to string variable for future input into sql table (I do not want to echo the result)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have read most of the questions here and read the php manual in regards to the problem of converting an sql result to a string, however none of them is working for me. The examples given I understand, however they are echoing the sql results, I do not want the result to be echoed, I just want it to be stored in a variable so I can immediately insert it into a next sql table.

This is my code:

```
    $cnt_fips = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT cc_fips FROM location2 WHERE location_name = '$cnt'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cnt_fips);
```

These are the codes I have used to convert to string but failed with

```
    $myStr = !is_array($row) ? trim(addslashes($row)):'';
```

and

```
    $myStr = (string)$row;
```

and

```
    $myStr = print_r($row,true);
```

and also

```
    $myStr = (string)$row;
```

And insert into the table below

```
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO location3 VALUES ('','$myStr')");
```

Comment: `$row` is always an array with column names as the keys.  Use `$myStr = $row['cc_fips'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is always an array with column names as the keys, use:

```
$myStr = $row['cc_fips'];
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you can do that all in one insert with a sub-select (though maybe not if a row with `$cnt` doesn't exist). If so, maybe someone will post it.

Comment: yes `$cnt` might not exist, I do not want my users to input wrong countries. Thanks!